# How do I redirect to an external MP4 file link

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, video

i Created an HTML page and placed a Java script to redirect the page to an external MP4 file link, But when I put the page link in the HTML5 video player the video doesn't play, But a redirect link from the website to  shorten the links is playing video
[My page link to redirect](https://okoshiyasu.000webhostapp.com/video.html)

[link from a special website to shorten the links](https://2u.pw/vMJPW)

```html
This is the javascript code that I put on my page
<script> 
window.location = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4";
</script>
```

```html
<video  controls>
<source src="https://2u.pw/vMJPW" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```html
<video  controls>
<source src="https://okoshiyasu.000webhostapp.com/video.html" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Why are you using a web as src in the source of video?

Comment: In order to disable redirection if the visits are from other sites

Comment: Anyway. What is your problem? Why don't use the reduced link?

Comment: I have an mp4 file from an external link, 
I want to merge the external link with a local link, 
To become a contact on my domain, 
There are sites that extract links to YouTube MP4 files and link them to their own links, 
That is, the file link becomes in the private domain name without what it stores in its cloud